# failed Login throws error on registration page - magento 1.14 EE

Tags: php, magento

After a login with wrong credentials, it redirects to the registration page with the error is generated saying invalid login or password. Please assist I want this error to be displayed in the login page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay so it was a URL rewrite issue so I fixed it on the setting of my store by changing the login URL path from bla/bla/bla/**create**.to bla/bla/bla/**login**